# Sending calls to voicemail when I am in a meeting

Tags: hardware, automation, voicemail

If my aCalendar, or any calendar for that matter, has an appointment, I would like the phone to recognize that I am in a meeting and the call then vibrates or is silent etc.

For instance:

- If I am in church, I want the phone to register this and then direct the call to voice mail.
- If I am in a meeting, I would like the option to have calls come through or go to voicemail.

I do not want a blanket approach, but I would like to be able to set this on a meeting by meeting basis. I have looked at the Llama app and may try to Tasker app, but there must be something built into the phone that will allow this.

Comment: I use Tasker for this. As far as I know there is nothing built in to Android to do this.

Comment: @ZnewmaN could you post an answer detailing what exactly you do with tasker to do this. I am interested in this as an answer.

Comment: @RyanConrad I posted an answer to the pushing calls while in business meeting to voicemail. I can do the same for location awareness if you would like.

Answer (score 3):

Using tasker you can accomplish this and more fairly easily once you know how to use it. To solve the whole phone ringing while you are in a meeting you have a few options with how to do it in Tasker. You can choose to silence your phone while in meetings, set it to vibrate, block all phone calls (probably not the best choice) or send them all to voicemail. I will go through how to create a profile for the latter.
First, Create a new profile:

[image: Create a new Profile]

Next select State, then App, and then Calendar Entry

[image: Select State] [image: Select App] [image: Select Calendar entry]

For the Calendar entry settings you need to make sure to select **No** for availability and then you can click the magnifying glass next to Calendar to select which calendar it should be referencing. Then click the check mark.

[image: Calendar Entry Settings]

Now to create a task to do during that meeting. Select New task and then click the plus (+) sign in the lower left corner.

[image: New task] [image: Click plus]

For the action select Phone and then Select End Call and then the check mark

[image: Select Phone] [image: Select End Call]

Once you have done that you can click the check mark to close and save the task. Go to the Profiles tab at the top, then click on your Profile you created and long press on the Context below it (the Calendar setting on the left). This should bring up a Context menu. Select Add and then Event.

[image: Select Add] [image: Select Event]

From Events select Phone and then Phone Ringing.

[image: Select Phone] [image: Select Phone Ringing]

Now you have a Profile to push phone calls to voicemail when you are in meetings.

Comment: Am curious, did you have to edit the images first before-hand to illustrate... its neat...

Comment: @t0mm13b Nope, in Android under Settings> Developer Options there is a "Show touches" check box and if you hold the touch while taking screenshots it gets captured.

Comment: Clever!!!! That's a bloody useful tip!!!! +1 from me!!!

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look at [Silence](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.epsilonlabs.silence.ads).

It primarily turns off audio alerts/ringtones on schedule but can also manipulate wifi and mobile data and is pretty granular. It also recently added the ability to use events on Google Calendar.

I use it to turn off the ringer (I like to sit in the quiet car) and wifi (there's none to connect to) during my commute on the train, and also to set the phone to vibrate during a meeting.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an app called [Free Busy Silent Mode](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.zlift.fbs). It does not direct the call to voicemail, but you have an option to set the phone to silent